# Finding the same string inside a string mulitple times

Tags: c++

How would you go about trying to find a certain std::string **str2** that could be in std::string **str1** multiple times and storing the positions in a list or vector?
I'm asking for a rough idea and it's good enough to leave out trying to store the whole position of the word by str2.length().

Comment: do you know how to find the first occurence of `str2` in `str1` ? Please show some code, explain what you tried and how it fails. SO is not a codewriting service

Comment: I did try std::find with std::size_t but that seems to work only for one occurance. It may be that don't know of a working method so far

Comment: ...next question would be: what did you notice when you called `std::find` ? What do you pass as first parameter (or second parameter if you use `std::string::find`)? ...anyhow, you already got your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::string::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) takes a `pos` parameter, that tells it where to start searching. So you can create a simple loop using the last pos it found (starting at 0):

```
std::vector<size_t> positions;
std::string str1{"blabliblablubla"};
std::string str2{"bla"};
size_t pos = 0;
while((pos = str.find(str2, pos)) != std::string::npos)
{
    positions.push_back(pos);
    pos++;
}
```

Comment: `size_t pos = -1;` is slightly cheeky. I mean, it works, but you're relying on some very specific wraparound behavior here.

Comment: @melpomene Valid point.